# House Warming ceremony

Tags: rituals, practice

What does the hindu scriptures says about doing House warming (Grehaprevesham) ceremony if family member has died recently. Can it be done or are there any restrictions?

Comment: The ashaucha lasts for 10 days and after purification ritual on 12th/13th day you can resume normal activity. In your case 12/13th day should be getting over on 9th/10th august. So grihapravesha can be done on 20th. Also note: prohibitions do not apply on your father’s side (you and mummy). They apply only only to you if you are the main guy doing the funeral.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.
One more clarification on the same post : 
I (Grandson) was part of the funeral activity and went till crematorium, involved in all kriyas till her Kshariram(Human Body)  is sent to furnace. 
So can we perform grihapravesha on 20th. please clarify .

Comment: Yes the ashaucha will be over on 9th/10th so you can perform

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance.